# trying to extract tags from HTML page

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I need to find all nodes of an HTML page that have a structure `<h2><span class="mw-headline" ...> ... </span></h2>`, `<h2>...<\h2>` pairs determining the beginning & end of the nodes. I tried to find nodes like so:

```
string raw_code = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/")[0].WriteTo(); // can there be more than 1 node there?
string[] lines = raw_code.Split('\n'); 
foreach(HtmlNode hdr in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class = \"mw-headline\"]"))
{
  int line_number = hdr.Line;
  int line_position = hdr.LinePosition;
  string font_tag = lines[line_number].Substring(line_position - font_tag_length, line_position);
  MessageBox.Show(lines[line_number]); // returns div c
}
```

The `MessageBox.Show()`, frankly speaking, shows anything but not it's meant to show, including `<div class="thumb tright">` and `<p>Mostly flat plains or gently rolling hills in north and west.</p>`.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please show example input instead of describing it. Small hint: You can also use single quotes in XPath, for example `@class = 'mw-headline'` -- no need for escaping double quotes.

Comment: It's not clear what you are attempting to retrieve but is there a reason you are using Line and LinePosition to get a substring when you could be using InnerHtml or InnerText or OriginalName?